# How to show windowsformshost control and wpf grid in same window?

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsformshost

I used WindowsFormsHost control to view pdf document in same window where I had grid control.Now grid is not visible when windowsformshost is visible.I need to display both control at the same time.

Please can anyone help me to display both control together.

this is my code

```
   ViewDocument doc = new ViewDocument("Hide", "R1B", "", "Chapters", "");
            doc.windowsFormsHost1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            var uc = new Pdfdocument(quespath);
            doc.windowsFormsHost1.Child = uc;
            doc.Show();

    if (fmtyp == "Hide")
        {
            transgrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

XAML Code -

```
<Canvas Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.RowSpan="6" Margin="3,0,0,1" Name="canvas1" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="6">
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" Visibility="Hidden" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="0" Height="557" Width="881" />
        <Grid Name="transgrid" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="0" Height="557" Width="875">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/RaptorHscIIBlueprint;component/Images/1409934598_Help.png" />
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
 </Canvas>
```

Comment: well care to show code ?

Comment: add your xaml code as well

Comment: hi @Muds this is my code.

Comment: yea show us your grid as well

Comment: <Canvas Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.RowSpan="6" Margin="3,0,0,1" Name="canvas1" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="6">
            <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" Visibility="Hidden" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="0" Height="557" Width="881" />
            <Grid Name="transgrid" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="0" Height="557" Width="875">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/RaptorHscIIBlueprint;component/Images/1409934598_Help.png" />
                </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>

Comment: I mean your XAML code, where all these controls are defined

Comment: @Muds here i have mentioned xaml code.sorry i am new for this

Comment: i defined these two in a wpf window

Answer (score 0):

Your controls reside on top of Each other -- try this --

```
<StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.RowSpan="6" Margin="3,0,0,1" Name="stackPanel1" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="6">
    <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" Visibility="Hidden" Height="557" Width="881" />
    <Grid Name="transgrid" Height="557" Width="875">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/RaptorHscIIBlueprint;component/Images/1409934598_Help.png" />
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: sorry @muds .its not working . i need to show grid on windowsformshost control

Comment: there is an image as background, that will overshadow your control

Comment: in that windowsformshost i want to show pdf document.here i want to keep grid on windowsformshost.it will display one by one when using stack panel.